# Espaçamento entre botões JSF

Tags: jsf, xhtml

Estou entrando no mundo JSF e estou tentando criar uma calculadora mas não estou conseguindo deixar os botões sem espaço, eles precisam ficar juntos, alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

```
    <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:commandButton value="7" />
                <h:commandButton value="8" />
                <h:commandButton value="9" />
                <h:commandButton value="/" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize os atributos `cellpadding` e `cellspacing` para retirar o espaços entre as células:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <h:commandButton value="7" />
        <h:commandButton value="8" />
        <h:commandButton value="9" />
        <h:commandButton value="/" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Ainda mostra os espaços.

Comment: Verifique se não tem algum css seu interferindo o css do panelGrid